# Using LINQ/Lambdas to copy a String[] into a List<String>?

Tags: c#, linq

What's the correct C# syntax to do the following using sexier syntax?

```
string[] arr = ///....
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

foreach (var i in arr) {
   lst.Add(i);
}
```

I feel like this could be a one liner using something like:
  arr.Select(x => lst.Add(x));

but I'm not quite bright enough to figure out the right syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

.ToList() is fine, but to be honest, you don't need LINQ for that:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(arr);
```

Comment: While I appreciate that this is clearly more efficient than any other way of doing it, I was asking the question to better understand the C# syntax.

Answer (score 11):

```
List<string> lst = arr.ToList();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx

Comment: While I appreciate that this is clearly more efficient than any other way of doing it, I was asking the question to better understand the C# syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`list.AddRange(arr)` ?

Answer (score 2):

.Net 2.0:

```
lst.AddRange(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this...

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "Hello", "Bonjour", "Hola" };

List<String> lst = arr.ToList();
```

If you are missing the `.ToList()` method you might need to add `using System.Linq;` to your code...

Thanks **:)**

Answer (score 0):

```
  string[] arr = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
  var lst = new List<string>();
  Array.ForEach(arr, x => lst.Add(x));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I was looking for, though I feel that the Array.ForEach seems a little superfluous.  Isn't there something a little bit more generic that can be arbitrarily applied to anything that is Enumerable?